# WP_query has incorrect wp_posts.post_name = 'asc' when I have custom post type called 'order'

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, sql

This is my code :

```
print_r($args)

//Output 
array(6) { ["post_type"] => string(9) "order" 
           ["date_query"] => array(2) { 
               ["before"] => string(3) "now" 
               ["compare"] => string(1) "=" 
           } 
           ["post_status"] => string(9) "validated" 
           ["posts_per_page"] => int(-1) 
           ["orderby"] => string(5) "title"
           ["order"] => string(3) "ASC" 
         }
```

And this is the request :

```
$wp_query = new \WP_Query( $args );
var_dump( $wp_query->request );
  
//Output 
"SELECT wp_posts.* 
 FROM wp_posts 
 WHERE 1=1 
 AND ( wp_posts.post_date < '2020-08-07 16:46:27' ) 
 AND wp_posts.post_name = 'asc'
 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'order'
 AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'validated'))
 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC "
```

So WP_Query in the query says `wp_posts.post_name = 'asc'` !!!

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is :

My custom post type is "order"

So `$args['post_type'] = "order"`

And `$args['order'] = "asc"`

And for some reason `WP_Query` made `wp_posts.post_name = 'asc'`

> I fixed this adding a prefix for my custom post type name like `foo-order` so `$args['post_type'] = "foo-order"`